# Android Superclass to Subclass casting

Tags: java, android, android-studio, downcast

I'm using Android Studio to develop for Android.
I tried this

```
MarginLayoutParams mlp;
LayoutParams lpms = new LayoutParams(5, 5);
mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) lpms; //Throws Class cast exception
```

But it causes ClassCastException. Why? MarginLayoutParams is a subclass of LayoutParams.
I also tried to use instanceof, but it returns false. How can I do casting?

Update:
I found this code in Cyanogenmod Calculator app on GitHub:

```
final View childView = getChildAt(childIndex);
final MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) childView.getLayoutParams();
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do casting?

You can't. The type of `lpms` is not a `MarginLayoutParams` or any of its subclasses

Comment: But what about downcasting in java? I found [this code](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Calculator/blob/cm-12.0/src/com/android/calculator2/CalculatorPadLayout.java) in Cyanogenmod Calculator app, so may you explain me what is wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: You can downcast if the type is already a `MarginLayoutParams` or a subclass but you happen to have a `View` reference. `MarginLayoutParams` is not to be found in the `LayoutParams` [object hierarchy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html). In fact the opposite is true.